# SQL Server : I want to access Json Array of object

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max),
        @errors varchar(max),
        @policy_number varchar(10)

SET @json = 
    '{
        "returnMessage": "",
        "policy_number": "12345",
        "documents": {
            "policy_document": "",       
            "tax_invoice_document": ""
        },
        "errors": [
            {
                "error_code": "999", 
                "error_message1": "Error"  
            }
        ]
    }'
```

I want to get `Error_code`, `error_message1`

```
SELECT
    @policy_number = policy_number,
    @errors = errors
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json) WITH 
                    (
                        policy_number VARCHAR(10) '$.policy_number', 
                        errors VARCHAR(max) '$.errors'
                    )
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: If you want to store raw json in the DB, that's fine, but any field within the json you may need to use with a query you should also provide it's own column in the schema and extract at the time of insert or update, usually in the client code. MUCH better to do the extraction _once_ at record save, rather than _every time the table is queried_, plus then you can index the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.  You need `AS JSON` in your `OPENJSON` and then you can use CROSS APPLY to pull your desired values out of `errors`.

```
declare @json varchar(max),@errors varchar(max),@policy_number varchar(10)
set @json = 

    '{
        "returnMessage": "",
        "policy_number": "12345",
        "documents": {
            "policy_document": "",       
            "tax_invoice_document": ""
        },
        "errors": [
            {
                "error_code": "999", 
                "error_message1": "Error"  
            }
        ]
    }';

SELECT error_code, error_message1
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (errors NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) l1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(l1.errors)
WITH (
    error_code VARCHAR(100),
    error_message1 VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Comment: Is work fine if ERROr have multple data so how can in variable put in variable and 
set @json = '{
    "returnMessage": "",
    "policy_number": "12345",
    "documents": {
        "policy_document": "",       
        "tax_invoice_document": ""
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "error_code": "999", 
            "error_message1": "Error123"  
        },
  {
            "error_code": "8888", 
            "error_message1": "Error1234"  
        },
  {
            "error_code": "7777", 
            "error_message1": "Error1234"  
        }
    ]
}'

Answer (score 1):

If you only want data from the `errors` property, you can go straight to that with a single `OPENJSON` call

```sql
DECLARE @json varchar(max)

SET @json = 
    '{
        "returnMessage": "",
        "policy_number": "12345",
        "documents": {
            "policy_document": "",       
            "tax_invoice_document": ""
        },
        "errors": [
            {
                "error_code": "999", 
                "error_message1": "Error"  
            }
        ]
    }'

SELECT
    policy_number = JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.policy_number'),
    error_code,
    error_message1
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.errors')
    WITH (
        error_code VARCHAR(100),
        error_message1 VARCHAR(100)
    );
```

Comment: @Huzefa This is actually a better approach than mine if if you just want the error_code and error_message values.  If you need any of the higher up property values then you would want to start getting into multiple OPENJSON calls as my approach used.